# Increasing size of bitmap image in splash screen

Tags: android

I am creating a splash screen for android using drawable xml, and my 
back_splash.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
    android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>


    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Now the Issue is if I keep `android:gravity="center"`  in bitmap, it makes my image too small for all devices.
If I keep this property in item it makes image ok for small phones but make it horrible for tabs.

I have tried everything, like using mimap (where I have all sizes of image) , using drawable where I have kept different sizes of nine patch image, but nothing seems to make the image look good. 
(I have created ninepatch image using an online tool)

Now as keeping android:gravity="center" makes it just small (not blur), I want to know if I can increase this image size a bit more, using any work around?
I have wasted a lot of time to make it work, but nothing useful.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: Yes I posted my answer

Answer (score -5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<item android:gravity="center">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</item>
```

Comment: But it still shows the bitmap of a very small size. How do you increase the size of the same?

Comment: I noticed that the size of image which I keep in  app/src/res/drawable/ folder..  , it takes the same size of image for splash screen. so with above changes and proper size of image in drawable, it worked for me. Please note its only drawable folder.. drawable-hdpi etc are not affecting it

Comment: @gonephishing remove all icons from drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi
keep only one icon that is in folder name drawable.and then android will pick that icon of which ever size you keep.